# How can I print in the main program the result of a function within another function in Python?

Tags: python, function, nameerror

*****UPDATE: **Thanks to everyone who contributed. The code is alright. I figured there was a problem with the website I was using as IDLE.**

I have to write a program in Python that calculates then prints specific information about a loan. The program (code below) consists of 2 functions and I have written them correctly. The only problem I have is that I have to write the second function within the first one. When I run the code, I get this error: `NameError: name 'vaam' is not defined`
I've just started coding last week, I hope you guys help me out with this.
Here's my program:

```
# Your function for calculating payment goes here
def loan(principal,annual_interest_rate,duration):
r=(annual_interest_rate)/1200
n=duration*12
if annual_interest_rate==0:
    monthly_payment=principal/n
else:
    monthly_payment=(principal*(r*(1+r)**n))/((1+r)**n-1)
return monthly_payment
  # Your function for calculating remaining balance goes here
   def vaam(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration , number_of_payments):
    n=duration*12
    r=(annual_interest_rate)/1200
    
    if annual_interest_rate==0:
        remaining_loan_balance=principal-principal*(number_of_payments/n)
    else:
        remaining_loan_balance=(principal*((1+r)**n-(1+r)**number_of_payments))/((1+r)**n-1)
    return remaining_loan_balance

 # Your main program goes here
 principal=float(input("Enter loan amount: "))
 annual_interest_rate=float(input("Enter annual interest rate (percent): "))
 duration=int(input("Enter loan duration in years: "))
 print('LOAN AMOUNT:',int(principal),'INTEREST RATE (PERCENT):',int(annual_interest_rate))
 print('DURATION (YEARS):',int(duration),'MONTHLY PAYMENT:',int(loan(principal,annual_interest_rate,duration)))
 for i in range(1,duration+1):
  print('YEAR:',i,'BALANCE:',int(vaam(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration , i*12)),'TOTAL PAYMENT:',int(loan(principal,annual_interest_rate,duration)*12*i))
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's critical for Python

Comment: Are you sure to have to write the second function within the first on?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: If you don't fix the indentation in the question, it's really hard for us to help. Please follow the PEP-8 recommendation of 4 spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# Your function for calculating payment goes here
def loan(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration):
    r = (annual_interest_rate) / 1200

    n = duration * 12
    if annual_interest_rate == 0:
        monthly_payment = principal / n
    else:
        monthly_payment = (principal * (r * (1 + r) ** n)) / ((1 + r) ** n - 1)
    return monthly_payment


# Your function for calculating remaining balance goes here
def vaam(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration, number_of_payments):
    n = duration * 12
    r = (annual_interest_rate) / 1200

    if annual_interest_rate == 0:
        remaining_loan_balance = principal - principal * (number_of_payments / n)
    else:
        remaining_loan_balance = (principal * ((1 + r) ** n - (1 + r) ** number_of_payments)) / ((1 + r) ** n - 1)
    return remaining_loan_balance


# Your main program goes here
principal = float(input("Enter loan amount: "))
annual_interest_rate = float(input("Enter annual interest rate (percent): "))
duration = int(input("Enter loan duration in years: "))
print('LOAN AMOUNT:', int(principal), 'INTEREST RATE (PERCENT):', int(annual_interest_rate))
print('DURATION (YEARS):', int(duration), 'MONTHLY PAYMENT:', int(loan(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration)))
for i in range(1, duration + 1):
    print('YEAR:', i, 'BALANCE:', int(vaam(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration, i * 12)), 'TOTAL PAYMENT:',
          int(loan(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration) * 12 * i))
```

Output

```sh
Enter loan amount: 5000
Enter annual interest rate (percent): 8
Enter loan duration in years: 5
LOAN AMOUNT: 5000 INTEREST RATE (PERCENT): 8
DURATION (YEARS): 5 MONTHLY PAYMENT: 101
YEAR: 1 BALANCE: 4152 TOTAL PAYMENT: 1216
YEAR: 2 BALANCE: 3235 TOTAL PAYMENT: 2433
YEAR: 3 BALANCE: 2241 TOTAL PAYMENT: 3649
YEAR: 4 BALANCE: 1165 TOTAL PAYMENT: 4866
YEAR: 5 BALANCE: 0 TOTAL PAYMENT: 6082
```

The issue is with your indentation, you put `vaam` function under `loan` function.

Comment: Thanks, but I _have to_ put 'vaam' function under 'loan' function

Comment: can you tell me why you have to do that, like what are you trying to achieve? I run the code and everything works fine

Comment: I just edited the answer to add the output I got when i run the code

Comment: I also ran the code and it worked fine. Problem is, this is part of a Python course I'm taking, and while my initial code (the same code you wrote) works ok in my IDLE, the course's website gives me an error. And because there was an explanation before that question, saying we should implement a function in another one, I thought this is what I should do with this.

Comment: ok, i will suggest you put the `vaam` function before the `return` keyword in the loan function